# How to get coordinates from AutoCAD using PyAutoCAD

Tags: python, autocad

I am trying to work with AutoCAD and PyAutoCAD.  I would like to pass the coordinates from a picked point in AutoCAD into Python.  I have the basic example running so I know how to draw lines.

Basic Example Code

```
# importing pyautocad
from pyautocad import Autocad, APoint
# creating AutoCAD instance
acad = pyautocad.Autocad()
print(acad.doc.Name)
p1=APoint(0,0)
p2=APoint(10,10)
acad.model.AddLine(p1,p2)

#get picked point

#do something with picked point
```